# subprocess gunzip throws decompression failed

Tags: python

I am trying to gunzip using subprocess but it returns the error -

> ('Decompression failed %s', 'gzip: /tmp/tmp9OtVdr is a directory -- ignored\n')

What is wrong?

```
import subprocess
transform_script_process = subprocess.Popen(
                            ['gunzip', f_temp.name, '-kf', temp_dir],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)(transform_script_stdoutdata, transform_script_stderrdata
                     ) = transform_script_process.communicate()
self.log.info("Transform script stdout %s",
                                  transform_script_stdoutdata)
if transform_script_process.returncode > 0:
shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
raise AirflowException("Decompression failed %s",
                                               transform_script_stderrdata)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you elaborate on which part of the error you find confusing? (It seems pretty self-explanatory, no?)

Comment: hmm.. newbie to python so confused where the problem is..

Comment: What's the name of the file you are trying to gunzip? What's the value of `f_temp.name`, what's the value of `temp_dir`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `gunzip` process and passing it the following parameters:

- `f_temp.name`
- -kf
- `temp_dir`

I'm assuming `f_temp.name` is the path to the gzipped file you are trying to unzip. `-kf` will force decompression and instruct gzip to keep the file after decompressing it.

Now comes the interesting part. `temp_dir` seems like a variable that would hold the destination directory you want to extract the files to. However, gunzip does not support this. Please have a look at the manual for gzip. It states that you must pass in a list of files to decompress. There is no option to specify the destination directory.

Have a look at this post on Superuser for more information on specifying the folder you want to extract to: https://superuser.com/questions/139419/how-do-i-gunzip-to-a-different-destination-directory

Comment: Thanks @Robbietjuh